# Java 8 Hibernate Streams Criteria groupingBy erasure type?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, java-stream, type-erasure

I have trying to get involve more with Java 8 beautiful && wonderful API.

Here is my code

```
private final Map<String,List<Student>>getStudentsAsStreamAndCollect()
{
    final Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class) 
    .setMaxResults(10);        
    return (Map<String,List<Student>>)criteria.list()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSingle));    
}
```

This works great, I would love do something like this:

```
private final Map<String,List<Student>>getStudentsAsStreamAndCollect()
{
    return currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class) 
    .setMaxResults(10)        
    .list()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSingle));    
}
```

But a compilation error arise:

```
 incompatibles types Object cannot be cast to Map<String,List<Student>>
```

I know this has to do with erasure type at compilation.

This seems to work:

```
private final Map<String,List<Student>>getStudentsAsStreamAndCollect()
{
    final List<Student> students = currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class) 
    .setMaxResults(10);        
    .list();
   students.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSingle));    
}
```

My question is if i already know the type of the collection returned by Hibernate

```
currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class)
```

There is some approach to be able to do:

```
private final Map<String,List<Student>>getStudentsAsStreamAndCollect()
{
    return currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class) 
    .setMaxResults(10);        
    .list()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSingle));    
}
```

Or is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t help that *you* know the type of the collection returned by Hibernate, if the return type of `Criteria.list()` is declared as the raw type `List` without type argument, the compiler doesn’t know.

Regardless of which approach you use, it involves at least one *unchecked* operation.

The best of your variants is the one where you assign the `List` to `List<Student>` as here the *unchecked* operation takes place right at the point where the API forces you to do it, by casting the result of `Criteria.list()` from `List` to `List<Student>`. Then, all follow-up actions can be performed type safe (assuming that your assertion that the list contains `Student` instance is correct).

Note that this has nothing to do with type erasure, it’s just about *raw type* use. There is no type information to erase as the `Criterion` class didn’t have generic type information in the first place.

Comment: Very good answer how could be criteria.list(); signature should be like to dont be raw type and be with type argument just for my knowledge something like. createCriteria(Class type), List<Class<type>> or something thanks a lot..

Comment: If `Criteria` was a generic class, it was possible to declare `createCriteria` in a way that returns an appropriately typed instance whose `list()` method. Then it worked smoothly. Note that you could also fix it by casting each element: `criteria.list().stream().map(Student.class::cast). …`